# datetime entering value when one is not specified

Tags: python, validation, datetime

I'm currently learning Python and taken it upon myself to learn some data validation. One part I've gotten stuck on is date and time validation. This program takes a number of parameters including `date_start`, `time_start`, `date_end`, and `time_end`. The catch is I need them in ISO format. Once in that format I need to make sure they are valid. That's where I'm stuck.

```
from datetime import datetime

def validate_date(date_start, time_start, date_end, time_end):
    full_date_start = date_start + time_start
    full_date_end   = date_end + time_end

    try:
        formatted_time_start = datetime.strptime(full_date_start, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S").isoformat(sep="T", timespec="seconds")    
        formatted_time_end = datetime.strptime(full_date_end, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S").isoformat(sep="T", timespec="seconds")
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

date_start = "2017-06-29"
time_start = "16:24:00"
date_end   = "2017-06-"
time_end   = "16:50:30"

print(validate_date(date_start, time_start, date_end, time_end))
print("Date Start: " + date_start + "\nTime Start: " + time_start + "\nDate End: " + date_end + "\nTime End: " + time_end)
```

I was testing some of the code by removing the day for `date_end` and the output I got back was

```
2017-06-01T06:50:30
```

This check should have failed, or I believe it should have since a day was not supplied. Any help would be appreciated and if there is an easier way to do this, I'd take it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the value of `full_date_end` before the line that should fail is executed, you get this: `"2017-06-16:50:30"` and since the format you are looking for looks like this `"%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S"` it picks up the first digit of 16 as the day value and the second digit as the hour value.

To avoid this I would suggest using this format: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` as the second parameter of the strptime call. But this also requires for you to change the lines where you define full_date_start and full_date_end as:

```
full_date_start = date_start + ' ' + time_start
full_date_end = date_end + ' ' + time_end

try:
    formatted_time_start = datetime.strptime(full_date_start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").isoformat(sep="T", timespec="seconds")    
    formatted_time_end = datetime.strptime(full_date_end, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").isoformat(sep="T", timespec="seconds")
    ...
```

I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: does it not still autofill the day in?

Comment: It wasn't doing that before, it was just that the '16' was split in half, the '1' went to the day part and the '6' went to the hour part. By adding a blank space you are forcing to look for the day before the space and the hour after the space.

Comment: @Alter It does not. Since the format I had allowed the Day and Hour to "spill" into each other, when a value for the day was not specified, the hour would fill it. Adding the space clearly defined where the day and hour are. I get a ValueError when the format does not match. In addition it matches the format I needed, ISO Format.